# Add two commands in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I am using two commands, one to set size of frames  and other to add water mark to left top corner

This command set size of frames to 720*1280

String[] complexCommandOne = {"-y" ,"-i", path,"-strict","experimental", "-vf", "scale=720:1280","-preset", "ultrafast", output};

Below command add watermark to above output file

String[] complexCommandTwo = `{"-y" ,"-i", output,"-strict","experimental", "-vf", "movie="+pngpath+" [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=x=10:y=10 [out]","-s", "720x1280","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050","-preset", "ultrafast", fileName}`;

Both these commands take 3-5 minutes on 20 seconds video

I want to merge these  so that time can be reduced.

Any help. I am new i Ffgmeg

Answer (score 0):

Never seen such thing, but looks like it basically just using regular FFmpeg CLI syntax.

So it would be this, I guess:

```
{"-y", "-i", input, "-strict", "experimental", "-vf", "movie="+pngpath+" [watermark]; [in] scale=720:1280 [scaled]; [scaled][watermark] overlay=x=10:y=10 [out]", "-s", "720x1280", "-r:v", "30", "-b:v", "15496k", "-c:v", "mpeg4", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-r:a", "22050", "-preset:v", "ultrafast", fileName}
```

which woud normally look like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i INPUTFILE -strict experimental -vf "movie=LOGOFILE [watermark]; [in] scale=720:1280 [scaled]; [scaled][watermark] overlay=x=10:y=10 [out]" -s 720x1280 -r:v 30 -b:v 15496k -c:v mpeg4 -b:a 48000 -ac 2 -r:a 22050 -preset:v ultrafast OUTPUTFILE
```

What FFmpeg version do you have?
Because over 3.0 you can omit "-strict", "experimental" (it was needed to enable FFmpeg's own AAC audio codec when it was still considered as an experimental feature).